# java spring(3.*) project compiled at local eclipse fails at server

Tags: java, spring, unix, soap, apache-axis

I have a project running in prod server. I want to have the project set up and running in local eclipse to do changes in source code and validate it. Earlier, this project was handled by other team so it made to create one. I imported the project war in eclipse and ran it in tomcat server. It ran few transaction as expected but at a specific transaction it throwing error in UI as well in logs. On checking the logs, the related back end web service is throwing error as **Configuration error 2020 see logs** and custom response from service.

On trying different scenarios. 
I exported the project as war from the eclipse(just added project) and deployed it in the server and ran it, it throws the same error at the specific transaction and same error log as i got in local eclipse.

So my observation is,
Now newly compiled files giving those error.

I am just beginning stage of in development, i am facing challenges proceeding further.

My project uses
Spring(v3.*), 
struts 1, 
Axis2 web service, 
hibernate, 
jakarta tomcat 5.0.28 and Java 6 both in server and local.

The failing transaction functionality: It will call a web service and bring required data. This is where it throws the error in logs **Configuration error 2020 see logs** .

Comment: **Configuration error 2020 see logs**.. See the logs. Share the logs :)

Comment: Highlighted is the total logs

Comment: I have to doubt that. There are definitely log files you are missing on.

Comment: No, there is no other error logs

Comment: Please mention the name of the application server.

Comment: jakarta tomcat 5.0.28 and Java 6 both in server and local.

Comment: Edit that in the question so that I can remove my downvote. And let's focus on the solution.

Comment: @suriyan what does tomcat default `catalina.out` file say? that output should be part of the question.

Comment: That log file not present. I got the error in server.xml file only

Comment: I solved it guys, thanks for your time.